# Как указать относительно js файла путь

Tags: javascript, django

У меня есть файл:
*media/user_1/games/HTML5-canvas-game---POKEMON--master/HTML5-canvas-game---POKEMON--master/canvas.pokemon.js*

И рядом с ним есть директория images и внутри есть изоброжение:
*media/user_1/games/HTML5-canvas-game---POKEMON--master/HTML5-canvas-game---POKEMON--master/images/player.png*

```js
...
playerImage.src = "./images/player.png";
...
```

И когда я подключаю в html этот js файл с url: *localhost:8000/game/pokemon*
Выдаёт ошибку 404 потому что изоброжение *localhost:8000/game/images/player.png* не существует.

Я хочу чтобы оно искалось относительно js файла, тоесть относительно *media/user_1/games/HTML5-canvas-game---POKEMON--master/HTML5-canvas-game---POKEMON--master/* как это вообще можно сделать или это невозможно?

Comment: Как вы сам js файл подключаете?

Comment: @Александр через тег script

Comment: Это, конечно, много о чем говорит